# Is it possible to skip the last few layers during back propagation phase?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning

I am designing a model for machine learning using neural network.

During back propagation phase, I don't want to make the nodes weighting of the last few layers change. Is it mathematically possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In keras you can accomplish this by setting the trainable property to false. (https://keras.io/applications/#Fine-tune InceptionV3 on a new set of classes) However I will have to side with the other answer and ask you why you would ever want to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I was asking its feasibility

Comment: But I have shown you how this can be accomplished in keras. Just set the trainable flag for the last 5 layers to false and you have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I will omit mathematical explanation, just will explain how neural network will behave.

So, let's say that you have neural network with 5 layers, and at last fifth layer weights doesn't change. 
What will happen in that case?

Error from last layer will be propagated back to previous ( fourth ) layer, but without any changes, and four first layer will have to deal with ***additional transformation*** of error which was provided by output layer. Neural network with five layers will learn how to deal with this additional transformation of error. But question, why on earth you need to present this transformation of error?

Comment: I know I was asking a weird question. We are going to train a model separating the signal into voice and bgm. And we would like to use a pretrained model for cost calculation(which can determine whether a signal is voice or not). I know this is not a normal approach. But I would like to know its feasibility.